# Sparse Vector vs Dense Vector

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

How to create `SparseVector` and dense Vector representations

if the `DenseVector` is:

```py
denseV = np.array([0., 3., 0., 4.])
```

What will be the Sparse Vector representation ?

Comment: For those who read the title of "Sparse Vector vs Dense Vector" and were looking for an explanation of when to use which, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26706528/877069) has the information you're looking for.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Unless I have thoroughly misunderstood your doubt, the [MLlib data type documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/mllib-data-types.html) illustrates this quite clearly:

```java
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors;

// Create a dense vector (1.0, 0.0, 3.0).
Vector dv = Vectors.dense(1.0, 0.0, 3.0);
// Create a sparse vector (1.0, 0.0, 3.0) by specifying its indices and values corresponding to nonzero entries.
Vector sv = Vectors.sparse(3, new int[] {0, 2}, new double[] {1.0, 3.0});
```

Where the second argument of `Vectors.sparse` is an array of the indices, and the third argument is the array of the actual values in those indices.

Comment: Oh, I was not passing the right count of indices. 
SparseV = SparseVector(4, [0, 1, 2, 3], [0., 3., 0., 4.])

Comment: what is the significance of a dot after number ie 1. ?

Comment: The dot just indicates a floating point type. `1.` is equivalent to `1.0`

Comment: @MohitShah (i) It is literally the first code example on the linked documentation, and (ii) the answer also includes the example showing exactly how to create a sparse vector.

Answer (score 26):

Sparse vectors are when you have a lot of values in the vector as zero. While a dense vector is when most of the values in the vector are non zero.

If you have to create a sparse vector from the dense vector you specified, use the following syntax:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors;

Vector sparseVector = Vectors.sparse(4, new int[] {1, 3}, new double[] {3.0, 4.0});
```

Answer (score 1):

Dense: Use it when you are having high probability of data.
sparse: Use it when you are having less available data positions filled (i.e. you are having too many zeroes)
eg: {0.0,3.0,0.0,4.0}
for different Vectors it will be

```
val posVector = Vector.dense(0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 4.0)  // all data will be in dense

val sparseVector = Vector.sparse(4, Array(1, 3), Array(3.0, 4.0)) //only non-zeros are mentioned
```

Syntax ex: Vector.sparse(size of vector, non-zero-index, values)