# group points by their circles inside which they are located on a map

Tags: hash, graph, grouping, geometry

On a map, there are some base stations that provide wireless internet access services that can cover a circel area with a fixed radius and the base station itself as center.

There are some wireless signal receivers (call them c) in houses on the same map. These receivers are fixed in their locations.

Suppose each base station can be represented as a unique color on map.
For each receiver (c), if it can reach base station x, we mark it on the map with the color of the station x.

Finally, i need to group all receivers by the color. It means that all receivers with same color belogn to the same group.

I can solve the problem by brutal force with the following table.

```
table1: 
base_station_color receiver_names
 1                  c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6  
 2                  c1, c2, c3
 3                  c1, c2,     c4 
 4                          c3, c4 , c5, c6
 5                          c3, c4 , c5, c6
```

Based on the table, c1 and c2 belong to the same group because they have same color combinations of 1,2,3. And, C5, C6 also belong to the same group because they same color combations of 1,4,5.

But, c3 and c4 do not belong to the same group because c3 has no color of 3 but c4 has.

Then, the output will be like:

```
table2
group, receiver_names, 
 gr1    c1, c2
 gr2     c5, c6
 gr3     c3
 gr4     c4
```

Finally, I only need to select one receiver from each group as a repsentitive:
e.g.

```
 table3
 group, receiver_names, 
 gr1    c1
 gr2     c5
 gr3     c3
 gr4     c4
```

table3 is the final output.

The table1 size may be very large, 1 million rows and 100k or 1 million colmuns.

I cannot keep a so large file in memory. I do not want to use any database on a server.

Are there some efficient algorithms to solve this problem ?

Are there some special hash functions that can do the followings:

```
 hash(c1, c2, c3) = hash (c1, c3, c2)
```

which means that the final hash value does not depend on the ordering of the input sequence. It only depends on the contents of all input.

Or, are there some functions that can implement coloring mix-up calculation ?

```
 green + red + yellow = yellow + green + red
```

which means that the final color does not depend on the ordering of coloring and it only depends on the color components.

Comment: Imagine the following: Assign a bit to each sender (i.e. 2^i for each sender i). You may store the or-combination of bits for each house. Afterwards, the bit-combinations form numbers - each different bit combination a different number. Btw. you get an order as well (from the order of numbers).

Comment: @Scheff, thanks, but, what if we get a conflict for the bit or-combinations? e.g. sender 3 and sender 2, get 3 + 2 = 4, but for sender 1 and sender 4, get 1 + 4 = 5 , both are 5 but the receivers covered by 1 and 4 should be in a different group from receiver covered by 3 and 2, right ?

Comment: If sender 3 and sender 2 you have `(1 << 2) | (1 << 3)` = 4 | 8 = 12. Please, have a look at the answer of Woody1193. It seems he had the same idea like me.

Comment: Sorry, you didn't tag C. `<<` is bit-shift which is equal to power of 2. `|` is "bit-wise or" but it might be replaced by `+` as well. Thus, `1 << 0` = 2^0 = 1, `1 << 1` = 2^1 = 2, `1 << 2` = 2^2 = 4, etc.

Comment: @Scheff, thanks, but, I may have 1 million senders, for sender 1million, what is meaningful result of shift 1 million ?

Comment: These are big figures. Of course, a single 32 or 64 bit can't handle this. However, the scheme can be applied to integers with "arbitrary" length (as long as enough storage available). In C++, `std::vector<bool>` might be a candidate. For the needed bit-shifting and other logic operations, there might be added suitable functions or operators.

Comment: Thinking longer about this, optimization techniques could be a help. E.g. compress the bit patterns of houses with [Run-Length Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) or more sophisticated compressing algorithms. This would save storage space (at cost of time, of course). Though a million senders may exist, I guess there are always only a few in the relevant distance of a house. Thus, most station-bits of a house will be 0. So, [Sparse Vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31522893/7478597) is something else which comes in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

A receiver either has a color or it hasn't so you can consider each color to be a single bit and so long as you assign each color a specific index in the overall bit-order, you should be able to give each receiver a hash value that can be compared directly. For instance set red to bit-position 0, yellow to bit-position 1 and green to bit-position 2 and so on. Once you've done that, you can compare any two receivers using the XOR bitwise operator. For reference, `A XOR B` will return 0 if A and B are the same.

For example, you could have an enum that does the following:

```
enum Colors {
    Red = 0,
    Yellow = 1,
    Green = 2,
    Blue = 3
}
```

and then you just take all the colors you have for a receiver do:

```
hash = hash | (1 << color)
```

and finally you can do:

```
receiver_a ^ receiver_b
```

where `^` is the XOR operation.

In this situation, receivers with colors (Red, Blue, Green) or (Green, Red, Blue) or (Red, Green, Blue) would all correspond to hash value 13 or 1101 in binary. Running through the math:

```
hash = 0
hash = hash | (1 << 0) # Red = 0
print hash             # 1b
hash = hash | (1 << 2) # Green = 2
print hash             # 101b
hash = hash | (1 << 3) # Blue = 3
print hash             # 1101b
```

As you can see, it doesn't matter what order of receipt is; each color gets a specific, deterministic position in the overall hash value. Therefore, each color-combination will be unique and reproduce-able.

Essentially, this is a SAT representation of your data.

Comment: thanks, but could you explain "hash = hash | (1 << color)" with more details ? After a receiver got 3 colors, e.g. red, green, blue, how to get its hash code with your formula so that only the color types (not their input ordering ) determine the hash value ?

Comment: Right, so I was using the `enum Colors` to convert the color values into integer values. For example, `Red = 0`. Then I'm doing a bit shift - the `<<` operator - to determine the exact position in an integer that the color corresponds to. I then OR that with the existing hash for the receiver. So, if I have a receiver with colors red, green, blue (or any combination thereof) it'll correspond to value 1101b or 13 in decimal. Order does not matter because each color has an exact value in the hash

Comment: thanks, what if there are 1 million senders ? example , for sender 1 million, how to do the bit shift ? thanks

Comment: Wait, what's a sender in this context? I don't see that anywhere in your question

Comment: Okay, nvm I figured it out from the context of your question. If there's one million senders (which you assigned colors to in your example) then that enum would have 1 million entries and the millionth entry would have a value of 999,999 because you start at index 0. Then, your bit shift would look like `1 << 999999`

Comment: thanks, could you please explain what could be the result of "1 << 999999" ? Are there a bit vector with one million bit length ? thanks

Comment: @user3448011 Technically they're integers, just very large. The `<<` means bitshift. So, if I have an integer with a value of 1 and I do `1 << 4` I wind up with 16 or `10000`. So, `1 << 999999` would be a binary number with a length of 1,000,000 bits comprised of a single set bit followed by 999,999 unset bits. The actual implementation would depend on the language you use of course. In Python, for instance, you could contain all this data in a single integer. In C++, you'd have to use some data structure